# SQL Mach two table

Tags: mysql, sql, mach

I've 2 table.

Table1

- Has count about 2700 rows
- Colums: ID, NO, NAME

Table2:

- Has count about 300 rows
- Colums: ID, NAME

where:

```
Table1.NO = Table2.ID
```

I want to list Table1(2700 rows) but if Table1 doesn't contain  some of Table2's rows I want to write "NA"

How can i do that with SQL?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you want to output the Name from table2, if it's present, in which case:

```
SELECT 
    a.id,
    isnull(b.name, 'NA'),
    a.name
FROM
    table1 a
LEFT JOIN
    table2 b
    ON
    a.no = b.id
```

will do it for you (I've also output the id and name from table1).

**EDIT:**

Apologies, I didn't see the MySQL tag until I posted. You will need to use the `coalesce` function instead if `isnull`, like so:

```
SELECT 
    a.id,
    coalesce(b.name, 'NA'),
    a.name
FROM
    table1 a
LEFT JOIN
    table2 b
    ON
    a.no = b.id
```

Answer (score 1):

Try `LEFT JOIN` and `ISNULL` function like this below

```
SELECT ISNULL(Table1.Name,'NA')
FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN Table2
ON   Table1.NO = Table2.ID
```

Comment: is there ISNULL function in mysql?